# ASP.NET Session Cleared Online

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cloud, hosting

I created a sample app (the default one), ASP.NET MVC, with one controller only:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Session["Test"] = "OK";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = Session["Test"];

    return View();
}

public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

This is my `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.9.0" newVersion="5.2.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 9F5FF3AC-D123-4243-85B2-517FFA79F93A-->
```

I hosted on Godaddy: when the session is being cleared less than 1  minute and the about us page is not showing the supposed "OK" message.

You can check the behavior on http://m.elect-gen.com/. (GoDaddy)
I hosted on SmarterASP : http://shoushouleb86-001-site1.atempurl.com/
The session is not cleared.

On the development machine, all is working correctly.

The index page is setting the session, the "About Us" is displaying the session.